# Probability question involving derangements

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

$n$ married couples came to a dancing night. For a dance women randomly choose men, $X$ is the number of dancing married couples, we need to find the distribution of $X$ and its probability generating function.

**My attempt:**

If $k$ married couples are dancing, then there are $\binom n k$ ways to select those $k$ couples out of $n$, also all other $n-k$ women and $n-k$ men are mixed so that $n-k$ married couples do not dance together. The number of ways to do that mixing is the number of derangements for $n-k$ elements, i.e. $(n-k)!\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$. There are $n!$ possible ways to build dancing couples. Thus:

$$P(X=k)=\binom n k \frac{(n-k)!}{n!}\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}=\frac{1}{k!} \sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!} \tag{A}$$

$$g_X(t)=E[t^X]=\sum_{k=0}^{n}t^k\frac{1}{k!} \sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!} \tag{B}$$

I know that $g_X(t)$ is supposed to be $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(t-1)^k}{k!}$.

Any ideas how can I get there?

Comment: They match up numerically.  And I agree with your derivation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binomial expansion:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(t-1)^k}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{i = 0}^{k} \frac{1}{k!}  {k \choose i} t^i (-1)^{k - i}$$

Use $\sum_{x = 0}^b \sum_{y=0}^x f(x,y) = \sum_{y = 0}^b \sum_{x=y}^b f(x, y)$ as both are sums over $(x, y)$ with $0 \le y \le x \le b$:

$$  = \sum_{i = 0}^{n} \sum_{k=i}^n  \frac{1}{k!}  {k \choose i} t^i (-1)^{k - i}$$

Reverse the variable names for $i$ and $k$:

$$ = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \sum_{i=k}^n  \frac{1}{i!}  {i \choose k} t^k (-1)^{i - k}$$

Substitute $j = i-k$:

$$ = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \sum_{j=0}^{n-k}  \frac{1}{(j+k)!}  {j+k \choose k} t^k (-1)^{j}$$

Expand the combination:

$$ = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \sum_{j=0}^{n-k}  \frac{1}{(j+k)!}  \frac{(j+k)!}{k!(j+k-k)!} t^k (-1)^{j}$$

Tidy:

$$ = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \frac{t^k}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}  \frac{(-1)^{j}}{j!} $$